# AWS was working with react native app, expo and Amplify then it stopped working and sent error [GraphQLError: Request failed with status code 401]

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I'm using react native, expo and aws amplify and have an app set up with authentication and uses graphql query listUsers. The app was working fine but all of a sudden after about 3 weeks or so it just stopped working and sends the error

> [GraphQLError: Request failed with status code 401].

I tried using authMode: `'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'` as highlighted in ['Unauthorized' error when using AWS amplify with grahql to create a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140993/unauthorized-error-when-using-aws-amplify-with-grahql-to-create-a-new-user), but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution to the issue. I needed to extend my API Key because it expired. To update just go into the Data Modeling tab then click on the "Manage API authorization mode an keys". Go to API Keys and click "Extend for 30 days". In the top left click "Back to Data Modeling" and "Save and Deploy", wait for it to update and they app should start back working. I hope this saves someone the hours I spent resolving this.